# royalslider in magento not working after switch off of temp domain

Tags: jquery, magento

So I installed royalslider on one of my magento sites and it worked just fine when it was on a temporary domain. As soon as I pointed the domain to the site and am now using the actual domain, the slider isn't working, it's just displaying the images that are in the slider on the page. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the domain where you can see it: http://ultimatepd.com - I'm getting this JS error on the page, also:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
http://ultimatepd.com:471&host=ultimatepd.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I  have seen the link I think you missed to add the plugin ryalsider to include on the site.
You can add that plugin means the JS and CSS files then it will work fine :)